# User Control not working

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

http://binaryjack.com/userControl.aspx

Each record is displayed using a user control. I have the delete button embedded in the user control.

Recreate Problem: click the first DELETE button, the last row gets deleted; after this I have to click the delete button (any of them) twice to make it work.

1. Is it bad practice to use a User Control (combined with a placeholder) to display a bunch of records? I query to get all records and then use a Foreach loop to populate each User Control and insert each UC into the placeholder.
2. Why does the Delete button not respond correctly?

Comment: How can anyone possibly answer this? You should put some code man...

Comment: please post your source code.

Comment: Why aren't you populating a Repeater or ListView with data?  Why a user control for each record?

Comment: Hi TheGeek, the reason is that I have full flexibility with design on a user control. It seems to work great except when trying to use a control (e.g., button) within a user control that is repeated. I don't know much about how flexible a listview is w/ respect to layout. I'll look into listview to see what I can do with its templates. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code it is tough to say.  However, it appears to be a refresh issue.  If you hit delete then hit refresh, the record is gone.  Check how you are refreshing the data and you'll find the issue.